# Why can't I change a list within a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Why doesn't this work?

```
In [28]: my_list_o_lists = [ [], ["cow", "says", "moo"], [1, 2, 3] ]

In [29]: print(my_list_o_lists)
[[], ['cow', 'says', 'moo'], [1, 2, 3]]

In [30]: m0 = my_list_o_lists[0]

In [31]: m0 = [ "Where is my cow?", "No idea!" ]

In [32]: print(my_list_o_lists)
[[], ['cow', 'says', 'moo'], [1, 2, 3]]
```

I want to change the first item in my list to another list as issued in line 31. But it doesn't work. Very confused and googling didn't help.

I'm on python 2.7.3 (using ipython 0.13.1 in the above example).

Comment: Why not just do `my_list_o_lists[0] = [ "Where is my cow?", "No idea!" ]`?

Comment: You're just assigning `m0` to another list, not the original one. Do `my_list_o_lists[0] = ["Where is my cow?", "No idea!"]` instead.

Comment: Because in line 30, you have it backwards. You are simply binding the variable `mo` to `my_list_o_lists[0]` It is not a pointer, like C for example.

Comment: Note that in C setting a variable to a different value doesn't change the previous value either.

Comment: But in C you could use a kinda sorta similar construct to change an array of strings by setting a pointer to the string and then using that pointer to copy the new string to the array.

Comment: @drewk extending from that, nor is `m0` a variable in the traditional sense, it's just a name

Comment: @ Haidro, because it becomes really cumbersome when dealing with large nested lists with long names. Was looking for a shortcut. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `m0` has the value of `my_list_o_lists[0]`, but is not a reference to it.
So, manipulating `m0` will not affect `my_list_o_lists[0]`.
See this:

```
>>> my_list_o_lists = [ [], ["cow", "says", "moo"], [1, 2, 3] ]
>>> m0 = my_list_o_lists[0]
>>> m0 = [ "Where is my cow?", "No idea!" ]
>>> print m0
['Where is my cow?', 'No idea!']
>>> print my_list_o_lists[0]
[]
```

To solve this problem, just manipulate `my_list_o_lists[0]` instead of manipulating `m0`.
Otherwise, you can manipulate `m0`, and assign it's value `my_list_o_lists[0]`.
Something like:

```
>>> my_list_o_lists[0] = m0
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't change the list, you rebind the `m0` name to the new list. To change the list you need to change its content (like `m0.append('')`) or replace `my_list_o_lists[0]` with a new list (like `my_list_o_lists[0] = ['']`).

Answer (score 1):

m0 is a variable and not a pointer to index 0 of my_list_o_lists. Changing m0 will not affect my_list_o_lists.
If you want to replace my_list_o_lists[0], you need to do

`my_list_o_lists[0] = m0`

Full code should look like this:

```
my_list_o_lists = [ [], ["cow", "says", "moo"], [1, 2, 3] ]
m0 = [ "Where is my cow?", "No idea!" ] # Assigning value to variable m0
my_list_o_lists[0] = m0                 # Assigning value of m0 to list index 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with the variable `m0` that you're using. In Python, a variable is just a name that gets attached to an object. If you assign to the variable, you just attach the name to a different object.

In this case, you're first attaching the name `m0` to the object in `my_list_o_lists[0]`. Then in the next step you're rebinding the name to a new list object. That doesn't make the original object (which is still in `my_list_o_lists`) go away, nor does it change the original object. Only the name `m0` gets moved.

If you want to fix your issue, you need to do one of two things. Either reassign the contents of `my_list_o_lists[0]` directly:

```
my_list_o_lists[0] = [ "Where is my cow?", "No idea!" ]
```

Or, modify the existing list in place, rather than replacing it:

```
m0 = my_list_o_lists[0]
m0[:] = [ "Where is my cow?", "No idea!" ] # slice assignment reuses the list
```

Comment: Interesting. I knew you could copy a list using "new_list = old_list[:]" but not use it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Two variable names point to a single list only if the whole list is assigned to the other. eg)

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
b=a
b.append(10)
print a
```

outputs

```
[1,2,3,4,10]
```

But since you assign only a single element of a list, the new variable points to a different address, so the change doesn't work. so use

```
my_list_o_lists[0]=['']
```

try this

```
a=[[],[],[]]
b=a
b[0]=[1,2,3,4]
print a
```

Answer (score 0):

You have it a little out of order. Try something like this:

```
>>> m0=['Where is my cow?', 'No idea!']
>>> LoL=[ [], ["cow", "says", "moo"], [1, 2, 3] ]
>>> LoL[0]=m0
>>> LoL
[['Where is my cow?', 'No idea!'], ['cow', 'says', 'moo'], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Or:

```
>>> LoL=[m0, ["cow", "says", "moo"], [1, 2, 3] ]
>>> LoL
[['Where is my cow?', 'No idea!'], ['cow', 'says', 'moo'], [1, 2, 3]]
```